# When is the storage reclaimed for a resource that is no longer owned?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

There is a vector resource that is allocated in line 2 of the program below.
When the program ends, the vector resource is not owned.  If a resource is not owned at all, when does it get reclaimed? Is there an explanation using the terminology of Rust ownership semantics and lifetimes that could convince a programmer that this resource is indeed reclaimed?

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1,2];
    v = vec![3, 4];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when does [an unowned resource] get reclaimed?

In Rust terms, an item is *dropped* when it goes out of scope, which often (but not always) corresponds to the end of a block. When it is dropped, any resources that are part of the item are also released.

*Resources* can mean memory, as in the vector example, but it can also correspond to other things like a file handle or a lock. This is commonly referred to as Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII).

> convince a programmer that this resource is indeed reclaimed?

You can never convince someone who truly doesn't want to believe ^_^. However, you can implement [`Drop`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) yourself to see when an item is being dropped:

```
struct NoisyDrop(u8);

impl Drop for NoisyDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Number {} being dropped", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("step 1");
    let mut nd = NoisyDrop(1);
    println!("step 2");
    nd = NoisyDrop(2);
    println!("step 3");
}
```

This will have the output

```
step 1
step 2
Number 1 being dropped
step 3
Number 2 being dropped
```

You can see that the first variable is dropped when its binding is replaced as there's no longer any way to get to the `NoisyDrop(1)` value. The second variable is dropped when it goes out of scope due to the method ending.

> ownership semantics and lifetimes

Consider this example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1];
    v = vec![2];
}
```

Conceptually, it could be written as

```
fn main() {
    {
        let v = vec![1];
    }
    {
        v = vec![2];
    }
}
```

And this example

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1];
    let v2 = vec![2];
}
```

Could be rewritten as

```
fn main() {
    {
        let v1 = vec![1];
        {
            let v2 = vec![2];
        }
    }
}
```

These rewritings show the *lifetime* of each variable. Whenever you call a method with a *generic lifetime parameter*, the lifetime of the block will be the concrete value that gets substituted for the `'a` generic.